# Cannot delete Cloud Composer environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to delete the Cloud Composer environment that I created just to try it out. I got the following error.

> DELETE operation on this environment failed 9 hours ago with the
>   following error message: A lien to prevent deletion was placed on the
>   project by [serviceconsumermanagement.googleapis.com]. Remove the lien
>   to allow deletion.

[image]

But I don't remember putting any lien on it. Regardless, I check the liens and try to delete it anyway. The problem is that gcloud does not show me any lien.

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list                               
> Listed 0 items.
```

Since, other co-worker are also using this same gcp project, I can't just delete the project and start a new one. I'm wondering if anyone know anything about this?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe, check your default project in terminal or `cloud shell`, do you execute the `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list` command on the correct project ? If not add `--project XXX`.

Comment: @muscat I'm sorry for the late action, I added some additional comments below.

Answer (score 2):

To remove a lien from a project, you must have the `resourcemanager.projects.updateLiens` permission which is granted by roles/owner and roles/resourcemanager.lienModifier. Please, check if you are granted.

Follow the below steps to delete environments resources manually:

1. Delete GKE cluster, that corresponds to environment
2. Delete the Google Storage bucket used by environment
3. Delete the related [deployments](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/deleting-deployments) with:

`gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete <DEPLOYMENT_NAME> --delete-policy=ABANDON`

4. Then try again to delete the Composer environments with:

`gcloud composer environments delete <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --location <LOCATION>`

If it wouldn't help, the problem could be related to a misconfiguration with the Cloud Composer service account in your project. Service account requires the permissions that the `composer.worker` [role](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) provides to access resources in the Cloud Composer environment. Please refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) for more details about how to grant a role to a service account.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried all the method suggested in the answer including, checked that I have the permission, deleted the GKE cluster, deleted the bucket. As for the deployments, I check for deployments and found that I have 0 deployment so I cannot delete. I also checked the service account permission and found it have all the necessary permission. I will continue to see if there is anyway to get this deleted. Thanks